# Erro de sintaxe em outra maquina

Tags: python

Possuo uma maquina na qual o Python 2.6.6 esta instalado, em uma determinada parte de um *script* eu faço o seguinte comando:

```
with open('saida1.txt') as saida:
    for line in saida:
        if "]L" in saida:
            print line
```

No qual eu procuro a *string* "]L" no arquivo saida1.txt e imprimo a linha correspondente.

Executando o mesmo *script* com o mesmo comando em outra maquina com Python 2.4.3
apresenta erro de sintaxe no comando "open".

Saberiam me dizer se isso é por conta de versão, compilador ou algo do tipo?
Ou se existe outra forma de fazer o mesmo recurso?

Erro:

```
$ python teste.py

 File "teste.py", line 1
    with open('saida1.txt') as saida:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Adiciona o full traceback do erro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no [context manager (with ...)](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) que não existe antes de python 2.5, tenta o seguinte:

```
saida = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = saida.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "]L" in saida:
        print line
saida.close()
```

Ou de maneira a cobrir possíveis exceptions:

```
fout = None
try:
    fout = open("tests.txt", "r")
    lines = fout.readlines()
    # fazer o que petendes 
finally:
    if fout is not None:
        fout.close()
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, a minha primeira tentativa foi essa, porém ele não lê o arquivo da mesma forma.

Comment: @MaurícioSalin , vou colocar a maneira de ler linha a linha

Comment: Muito obrigado @Miguel

Comment: De Nada @MaurícioSalin, ainda bem que resolveu... Entretanto se isto for código para correr com difernetes versões de python mais vale deixar sempre assim, ou fazer uma verificação no início do código para ver com que versão vai ser interpretado

Comment: Feito, eu já desconfiava que era a versão, porem não tinha achado ainda outras formas de fazer a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia,
Não sou da are python, mas dei um google e achei isso:

```
open isn't missing in 2.4. What's missing is the with statement (added in Python 2.5 as PEP-0343)

To do the same code without with:

fout = open("text.new", "wt")
# code working with fout file fout.close() Note the fout.close() is implicit when using with, but you need to add it yourself without
```

O open foi introduzido apenas na versão 2.5+
Tente usar o código acima, e de uma pesquisada sobre o open 2.4;

[SyntaxError: invalid syntax on "with open" on python-2.4.3](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9413)

[What is the alternative for open in python 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995068/what-is-the-alternative-for-open-in-python-2-4-3)

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Bruno, realmente o problema esta na versão, vou tentar dessa outra forma e ler os tópicos enviados, valeu!

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou, não sou da area como já havia falado, mas tentar ajudar só custa tempo mesmo. Sucesso pra você e sua aplicação.